# How to play Audio file in Android QT?

Tags: android, c++, qt, qt-necessitas

i developed my application in QT, i am trying to port for android. my application working fine in android with few issues. the main issue is, i am not able to play the audio file when i am trying to put the audio file play Code i am getting error

```
QSound::play(FilePath);
```

Error: : -1: error: error: cannot find -lQtMultimediaKit
D:\Projects\test\demo.cpp:996: error: undefined reference to 'QSound::play(QString const&)'

my config: QT 4.8,QT Creator 2.5.83 and necessitas and windows XP

i am able to include the QSound Header file and using intellisense to type the QSound::Play no issue while typing when i am getting error on compilation. so i tried to look into the source folder and i found QSound.h header also.

How to play the Audio file in Android using QT?

Comment: did you include `multimedia` in your `.pro` file ? `QT+= multimedia`

Answer (score 1):

in may case it works properly with no errors
my code:

```
player->setMedia(QUrl("qrc:/new/prefix1/1.mp3"));    
// ok it works on windows  
//also works on android
```

Comment: things are NOT so bright: https://forum.qt.io/topic/127649/mp3-not-being-played-on-android/13

Answer (score 0):

Stumblend in this one while searching info, this looks useful: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qml-qtmultimedia-mediaplayer.html

Answer (score 0):

While the support of Audio for Android in QT is there, it's a journey through hell with the current release. If you want it stable in the end you'll end-up searching for external libraries anyway [Take a look here](https://forum.qt.io/topic/127649/mp3-not-being-played-on-android/13)

Answer (score 0):

this works for me

file .pro

```
QTPLUGIN += qtaudio_coreaudio
QT += androidextras
    QT += widgets
    QT += quickcontrols2
```

file in Resources:

```
player2->setMedia(QUrl("qrc:/new/prefix1/folder_x/file.mp3"));
    player2->play();
```